# How to test (pointers of) a code ported to 64-bit?

Tags: c, pointers, testing, 64-bit

I have ported a source code of a software (in c) which isn't 64-bit clean to 64-bit. Generally I have dealed with pointer-related issues; changing integers that contain pointers to longs, casts used at comparisons, etc. However, I have no idea how to test these. Since size of pointers is doubled, I deduced that it matters only if locations of pointed places are bigger than 0x0...0100000000 (8 zeros after 1) but how can I guarantee that? Should I run many things in my VM (OpenBSD) to fill base of memory or is there another solid way to do it?

In summary: How can I test a code to check that there will be no (pointer-based) memory errors on amd64?

Comment: Why change possible pointers in `int` variables to `long` instead of a proper pointer? This is especially important since `long` doesn't *have* to be 64 bits, e.g. Microsofts Visual C++ compiler still have `long` as 32 bits even on 64-bit systems.

Comment: As for your problem, can you please try and show us some code? Doesn't have to be actual or real code, just enough for us to get an idea what you do know and what you want to do.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I will use code in OpenBSD, as I research it is 64 bits on 64-bit Unix-like arch.s.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg As sample codes; I changed `if( (int) pointer1 < (int) pointer2)` to `if( (long) pointer1 < (long) pointer2)` or make integer "temp" at `temp = pointer3;` a long variable. If needed, I can give the diff file. I just wanted to know if there will be still arch-based memory errors.

Comment: My problem is the casting, it's simply not needed. If two pointers are related (i.e. they both point into the same memory area) then you can just use the comparison directly, no need for casting. So if you have two pointers into a single string, you can do e.g. `pointer1 < pointer2` without the casting. And if you need a temporary variable, declare it as a proper pointer and not a `long` (or other unrelated type).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the problem is, the code does not belong to me. So I am trying to stick to the original code as much as possible, to avoid any possible mis-work at any other part of the code. That temp variable is used in other functions as integer and I don't want to change the code much. A bit acting lazy, only changing castings and tranfers from/to pointers.

Comment: Even so, `intptr_t` is correct and also clearer then `long`.

Answer (score 1):

Run all automated tests the system has.

If the system doesn't have automated tests or if the automated tests have poor coverage then you need to create more tests, probably combined with manual testing.

It is imperative that you have an installation of the 32 bit version of the system to compare with.
That way you can distinguish between old bugs and bugs that were introduced during the porting. This is extra important if the system is new to you, so that you don't know intimately how it is supposed to work.

If the system is fairly large, it is probably a good idea to automate the process of running the same test against both versions and comparing the result (output files, database state, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to fill the memory. Allocating it is sufficient. Hwoever, remember that each program gets its own memory space. So the allocation should be made inside your program under test.

This doesn't test your pointers-to-functions, though. These are determined before the first line of code is ran, but with ASLR they'll probably end up above 4G anyway. (Do check this!)